# PHP Fatal error: Interface 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener' not found

Tags: testing, phpunit, listener, cakephp-3.0, fatal-error

I'm working on a **CakePHP 3.x** project on a Vagrant VM. My project has a single Test for a Controller. Project was setup using **composer** and phpunit is installed in **vendor** directory.

Running  `./vendor/bin/phpunit`  Tests throws the following error:

```
[vagrant@devenv-lamp ~/www]$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit Tests
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener' not found in /vagrant/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php on line 30

Fatal error: Interface 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener' not found in /vagrant/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php on line 30
```

I tried running PHPUnit for a single Controller as well - with the same results...

```
[vagrant@devenv-lamp ~/www]$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/TestCase/Controller/QuestionsControllerTest.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener' not found in /vagrant/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php on line 30

Fatal error: Interface 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener' not found in /vagrant/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php on line 30
```

I'm very new to PHPUnit and am running into a wall even without taking off the ground. Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like autoloading is not set up correctly.

In your [phpunit.xml](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html) you need to specify a bootstrap file. This can either be a custom script based on your project or in some cases it's as easy as using composer's autoload.php:

```
<phpunit
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/3.7/phpunit.xsd"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    ...
</phpunit>
```